# Find records through two intermediate models in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having some trouble trying to fetch some models via SQL in rails and I was wondering if anyone knows of a good solution for this particular problem. Basically, these are what my classes look like:

```
class SubscriberList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :subscription_list
end

class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :announcement
end
```

Now, I want to access all the Announcements for a SubscriptionList excluding duplicates. Is this possible? Can it be done with a single SQL query or is that just wishful thinking?

For example here's what I want:

```
class SubscriptionList < ActiveRecord::Base
  def announcements
    Announcements.joins(:messages).where(message: { subscription: {subscription_list: self} })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea is correct in general. Try this variant

```
Announcements.
  joins(messages: {subscription: :subscription_list}).
  where(subscription_lists: {id: self.id})

# opposite
SubscriptionList.
  joins(subscriptions: {messages: :announcement}).
  where(announcements: {id: self.id})
```

Notes:
 * these queries may return duplicates - so `uniq` can be added to them
 * `self` can be omitted (I wrote it to show that this is id of instance and avoid missunderstanding)

Comment: On `Announcement.joins(messages: {subscription: self}).where(subscription_lists: {id: self.id})`, I get ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError. This is what `.to_sql` says: `SELECT "subscription_lists".* FROM "subscription_lists" ORDER BY "subscription_lists"."id" DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: why `joins(messages: {subscription: self})` try `joins(messages: {subscription: :subscription_list})` Sorry missed `:`

Comment: You, good sir, are some sort of SQL wizard. My mind is blown. It worked perfectly.

Comment: One quick thing, how would I do the opposite? `SubscriptionList.joins(subscriptions: {message: :announcement}).where(announcements: {id: self.id})` doesn't work due to `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError`.

Comment: When you come to "Subscription" (`joins(:subscriptions)`) you have reference `has_many :messages` - it means next step should be `messages` (not `message`). I will update answer. Please test it because it is very easy to make a mistake without playing in console)